# Periodic Markov Chains

Tags: markov-chains, periodic-functions

What's the reason behind why sometimes an irreducible, periodic markov chain still converges, with some good choice of an initial distribution? Conceptually, this doesn't make sense to me, because it should always oscillate, right? Is there a good way to see why (and when) this could be true? What does the initial distribution have to satisfy in order for the periodic chain to converge?

Comment: You might be assuming the Markov Chain is irreducible -- the answer below shows what can happen if it's not

Comment: @Nate8 : Yes, I'm talking specifically about irredicuble Markov Chains. I should add it to the question.

Comment: @Nate8 Are you sure irreducibility removes the issue? I don't think it does. My first example in the answer is irreducible of course, though that example is rather trivial. Another example is $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple example: $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. The stationary distribution is uniform, but it's not ergodic because once you know the initial state you know where the process will be at any future time (depending on whether the time is even or odd). On the other hand, if you start at exactly the stationary distribution, then of course you have convergence, because the sequence of distributions is just constant.

In higher dimensions, the situation can be a bit less trivial. In general a periodic Markov chain's transition matrix has one or more eigenvalues which are not $1$ yet have magnitude $1$. It could happen that your initial distribution happens to have no component in the direction of those eigenvectors, in which case there is no component of the distribution available to oscillate forever. For example, with $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \end{bmatrix}$, if your initial distribution assigns the same probability to state $1$ as to state $2$, then the distributions will converge, otherwise they won't. Note that for instance $\begin{bmatrix} 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \end{bmatrix}$ is not actually stationary but if that is your initial distribution then you will see convergence, because the problematic right eigenvector is in the direction $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

This last example was reducible but that is not essential, for example $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is also periodic (for example, a path from 1 to 1 is always an even length).

Comment: Thanks @Ian, can you describe more the necessary condition for not oscillating forever and why that is? Also, does the fact that I'm only talking about irreducible chains change anything?

Comment: @ajfbiw.s You need the following: for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $P$ such that $|\lambda|=1$ and $\lambda \neq 1$, the initial distribution $p$ is orthogonal to all the right eigenvectors of $P$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. This will cause the expansion of $p$ into left eigenvectors to not involve the left eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: @ajfbiw.s As for irreducibility, not that much is changed. You do get a unique stationary distribution, but there are still irreducible periodic chains. My second example isn't one of them, but $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is. Again in this example you have convergence to the stationary distribution if and only if your initial distribution is orthogonal to the "bad" eigenvectors, which in this case means that $p_1+p_2-p_3=0$. So for instance you will have convergence with the initial distribution $\begin{bmatrix} 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Ian. I tried a few cases, and your rule, which basically states that the initial distribution has to be orthogonal to the eigenvector with eigenvalue equal to -1, seems to work. However, I don't think I understand your reasoning for why this is true. Can you explain why this rule works a bit more?

Comment: @ajfbiw.s So first let me comment that you can have a *complex* eigenvalue with modulus 1, for example if you have a deterministic cycle on more than 2 states. Anyway, you have that $p P^n = \sum_k c_k(p) \ell_k \lambda_k^n$, where $c_k(p)$ are the coefficients in the expansion of $p$ into left eigenvectors, $\ell_k$ are the left eigenvectors, and $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues. So you need $c_k(p)=0$ whenever $|\lambda_k|=1$ and $\lambda_k \neq 1$, otherwise that term of the sum will oscillate forever.

Comment: @ajfbiw.s It turns out that $c_k(p)=p r_k$ where $r_k$ is the $k$th right eigenvector. (Technically $r_k$ must be normalized in a certain way to have $c_k=p r_k$ in general, but $pr_k=0$ doesn't depend on how you normalize $r_k$.) This is an interesting relationship between left and right eigenvectors that you might want to look at.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Where / how can I learn more about these properties?

Comment: Pretty much everything I said here is just linear algebra (I've implicitly assumed all the relevant matrices are diagonalizable; there are some further technicalities in the nondiagonalizable case). The only thing that I think would be hard to find in a standard linear algebra book is that relationship between the left eigenvectors and the right eigenvectors. For linear algebra I am personally fond of Strang's text, at least once the student already has a basic understanding. (For a basic understanding I prefer Lay's text, though I wouldn't say I *like* Lay's text.)

Comment: Thanks @Ian. Also, what if there are no eigenvalues with magnitude 1 but not equal 1? Does that mean some chains don't ever converge?

Comment: @ajfbiw.s If there are none then the chain is not periodic and any initial distribution will converge.

Comment: oh, so if the chain is periodic, there is always going to be such an eigenvalue? So you can find a non-invariant initial distribution that converges for ALL periodic chains? (maybe not the "non-invariant" part, meaning the initial distribution found using your rule could be the same as the invariant distribution itself?)

Comment: It might have to be invariant, if all the eigenvalues have modulus 1 (like in my simple example). If any eigenvalues don't have modulus 1 then you are correct.

Comment: I see. So: For periodic chains that don't have modulus 1 eigenvalues (or don't have complex eigenvalues at all), the initial distribution found using your rule will not be the invariant distribution. So there are two initial distributions that can converge -- the invariant distribution itself, and the initial distribution found using your rule. (right?) However, you said that all initial distributions that converge will satisfy the rule you stated. So how does it logically make sense for the invariant distribution (which converges) to not also be the one found using your rule?

Comment: I think the negations and quantifiers are confusing you. A periodic chain has at least one eigenvalue other than 1 which has modulus 1. If the initial distribution of a chain on a finite state space is orthogonal to all right eigenvectors of modulus 1 which are not 1 then you have convergence to an invariant distribution (the only one, if the chain is irreducible). Some sufficient conditions are then that no such eigenvalues exist, or that the initial distribution is already invariant, but these are not necessary. My rule typically describes a wide class of "good" initial distributions.

Comment: Thanks! (I see now that the 'no such e-vals exist' case is not relevant). You said that using the rule, the initial distribution found is equal to the invariant distribution if ALL eigenvalues have modulus 1.  How about the case when not all eigenvalues have modulus 1. That is, say, there are 3 eigenvalues, and they are -1, 0, 2 (so only one of them have modulus 1 and is not 1).  In this case, the initial distribution calculated using your rule will be a distribution that is not the invariant. In this case, is the initial distribution = invariant default case 'discoverable" using your rule?

Comment: The eigenvalues for a transition matrix have modulus $\leq 1$, and one of them is always $1$. Anyway, what I'm saying is, take all the right eigenvectors of modulus $1$ which are not $1$. Call their span $V$. The initial distributions which converge to some distribution are exactly those in the orthogonal complement of $V$.

Comment: It could be that $V$ is empty, in which case its orthogonal complement is the whole space (so any distribution will converge). This is what occurs when the chain is not periodic. On the other hand, it could be that $V$ is the whole orthogonal complement of the span of the invariant distributions. In this case you will see convergence if and only if the initial distribution is already invariant. For a "generic" periodic chain, you are in neither of these cases, and so there is a *nontrivial* set of initial distributions that lead to convergence.

Comment: Oh... I see. Thank you so much!